# Problem with fullCalendar : today's day disappears

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

i have a problem with fullcalendar. i don't know why but when i reload my page, i wait 2 seconds and today's day disappears and the line is shifting. 
I do not know where the problem may come from.
Tanks a lot for your help

Edit: sorry for not having put code.
I thought it might be a classic problem that many had. Sorry again
Here is my code :

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {


    var events = <?php echo json_encode($events) ?>;
    var date = new Date();
    var d = date.getDate(),
            m = date.getMonth(),
            y = date.getFullYear();


    var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
    var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {

      locale: 'fr',
      plugins: ['interaction', 'dayGrid', 'list', 'googleCalendar', 'bootstrap', 'moment'],

      themeSystem: 'bootstrap',
      header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'dayGridMonth,listYear'
      },

      navLinks: true, 
      selectable: true,
      selectMirror: true,
      select: function (arg) {
        var start = moment(arg.start).format('YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm:ss');
        console.log(start); 


        $("#date").val(start);
        $('#addModal').modal();
        if ($('#addModal').modal()) {
          calendar.addEvent({

            start: arg.start,
            end: arg.end,
            allDay: arg.allDay
          });
          $.ajax({
            url: '<?= base_url(); ?>index.php/Admin/add_event',
            data: {start: arg.start, end: arg.end},
            type: "POST",
            success: function (response) {
              displayMessage("Updated Successfully");
            }
          });
        }

        calendar.unselect();
      },

      editable: true,

      eventLimit: true,
      displayEventTime: false, 

      events: events

    });

    calendar.render();
  });
```

[a screen capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EajMg.png)

Comment: Since you didn't provide any kind of code or other debugging information, how do you imagine we are going to have any idea what is happening either? We are not magicians or mind-readers. If you would like some help, please provide relevant information which we could use to try and solve the problem. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the update. There is nothing obvious in your code which could cause such an error. If I had to guess, I'd say maybe you have a CSS issue (perhaps a clash of rules or styles which are affecting the calendar). Try removing any custom or non-fullCalendar CSS from your page (including the fullCalendar bootstrap theme) and see if you still have an issue. If it works with the defaults, then restore that CSS bit by bit until it causes the problem again.

Comment: Thank you very much, I just did some tests, and it's the bootstrap theme that creates the bug. I will look how to resolve the conflict.
So, again : Thanks a lot !

Comment: That's interesting because it's meant to be supported. Perhaps you should check whether you used the right version of bootstrap in your page and included all the needed files. See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/bootstrap-theme for details - in summary, you must include the necessary CSS and JavaScript files for bootstrap 4.

Comment: While searching, I found that it had a conflict between my bootstrap file and my js file where I had a : "window.setTimeout (function () {
  $ (". alert"). slideUp (500, function () {
    $ (This) .remove ();
  });
}, 2000); "
I think there was a class "alert" on the current day

Answer (score 1):

The problem is solved.
I found that it had a conflict between my bootstrap file and my js file where I had a :

```
window.setTimeout (function () {
  $ (". alert"). slideUp (500, function () {
    $ (This) .remove ();
  });
}, 2000);
```

I think there was a class "alert" on the current day

Thanks a lot to ADyson